# Bootstrap 3 :navbar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to make top nav fixed at the top when scrolled down , following is my code that is not working please help me with it

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var menu = $('.menu');
    var origOffsetY = menu.offset().top;

    function scroll() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= origOffsetY) {
            $('.menu').addClass('sticky');

        } else {
            $('.menu').removeClass('sticky');

        }
   }
    document.onscroll = scroll;
});
```

**css**

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

<div class="container-fluid  menu">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default ">
    <div class="container" >
    <div class=" col-xs-3 visible-xs">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".js-navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
```

not posting full code for navigation as i just got standard navbar with bit of customization pleas help me why is it not working

Answer (score 1):

You can add navbar-fixed-top to your nav class, like this :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Look at this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7g4qt7kk/18/

Comment: that is supposed to be fixed top when scrolled   down upto a speficic height

Answer (score 0):

I setup a fiddle with your code and it seems to be working correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/t0gbdx64/

```
No code changes were made (stackoverflow requires a code block with a fiddle link)
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, I set up a fiddle with his code and it worked fine.